# Eureka: Form validation not up-to-date

Tags: ios, eureka-forms

I have a Eureka form that uses validation rules and `.cellUpdate()` to reflect the validation status for each form field. Additionally, I want to display the validation status of the whole form (by colouring/enabling an "OK" button). For this purpose I use the `valueHasBeenChanged` callback function in my `FormViewController`. I cycle through all rows and test for `row.isValid`. However, it seems that `isValid` reflects the status *before* the value actually is changed.

How can I achieve the intended mechanism in a clean way (that is, not fiddling with global variables or the like)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback is indeed called in `RowOf<T>.didSet`, but `isValid` gives the result of `validationErrors.isEmpty`. The `validationErrors` list in turn is updated *after* the row's internal `_value` has been set, causing the behaviour described in my question. As I understand, it is this way no matter what's the setting in the row's `validationOptions`.

My remedy is to call `row.validate()` in my `valueHasBeenChanged` function to explicitly trigger the validation before I read the row's `isValid` status. The cost of an additional call of the row's validation rules is negligible
 for me.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to implement on-click form validation is add the

```
.cellUpdate { cell, row in
  if !row.isValid {
    cell.titleLabel?.textColor = .red
  }
}
```

code to each of your rows, use `. validatesOnDemand`  as the validation rule for the row, then call `form.validate()` in your button action.

For example:

```
        <<< TextRow() { row in
            row.title = ""
            row.tag = "firstName"
            row.add(rule: RuleRequired())
            row.validationOptions = .validatesOnDemand
            }
            .cellUpdate { cell, row in
                if !row.isValid {
                    cell.backgroundColor =.red
                    cell.titleLabel?.textColor = .red
                } else {
                    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
                    cell.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
                }
        }

...

form.validate()
```